# GraalVM - Performance Issue A lot of time for invoke js method

Tags: javascript, java, performance, graalvm

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I've encountered a performance problem while using the GraalVM Polyglot API to run JavaScript scripts as a script engine. The specific section of code that invokes the JavaScript function seems to have a significant delay, taking approximately 400 ms on average when executed 6,000 times.

Interestingly, when I attempted to run the same JavaScript code using Node.js in the WebStorm IDE, it only took about 20 ms. This stark difference in rendering time has me wondering if such a substantial delay is to be expected when using GraalVM Polyglot.

I noticed that other script engines, such as V8 and J2V8, tend to complete this task in approximately 50 ms, which further highlights the performance gap I'm encountering with GraalVM.

Below is the code snippet I'm using:

Expected Behavior:
I'm hoping to optimize the execution time by utilizing the GraalVM Polyglot API more effectively. To provide some context, the story.json file contains around 50,000 rows of data, and the scripting method involves the usage of jsep for parsing and some Visitor Design Pattern, which includes recursion. The function call that contributes to the delay cotains a visitor design pattern and some call backs like this

javascript

```
val = callee.call(args);
```

ny Ideas?
If anyone has insights into how I might improve the performance of this code using GraalVM Polyglot, I'd greatly appreciate your suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Remember to adjust the title, expected behavior, and additional context as needed to accurately reflect your situation. Also, make sure to provide any relevant error messages, warnings, or any further information that might help the community understand your issue better.

```
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class GraalVM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Context context = Context.create()) {
            URL resourceURL = GraalVM.class.getClassLoader().getResource("script.js");
            URL resourceJson = GraalVM.class.getClassLoader().getResource("story.json");
            
            context.eval("js", Resources.toString(resourceURL, Charset.defaultCharset()));
            
            Value functionsObject = context.getBindings("js");
            Value processor = functionsObject.getMember("scripting");
            
            String subjectJson = Resources.toString(resourceJson, Charset.defaultCharset());
            
                        long sum = 0;
            int iteration = 6000;

            for (int i = 0 ;i < iteration; i++){
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                processor.execute(subjectJson);
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                sum += (end - start);
            }

            System.out.println("time took for invoking in average is: " + (sum / iteration));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting GraalVM to be more performant than other implementations? Have your read the documentation (https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/js/FAQ/#performance)?

Comment: Just wondering, should this be tagged with `java`? It seems to be about `javascript`

Comment: yes it's a Java that invoking js script,, graal vm is a js engine that written in java

Comment: Is this using a polyglot runtime with compilation enabled? What does `Engine.create().getImplementationName()` return? You mention something being executed 6000 times, since it don't see a loop in the Java code i assume it's happening in the javascript code?

Comment: @GillesD.

yes I'm using a polyglot engine.


the snippest of code is a sample of a production issue, BUT imagine this code is execute 6000 time, and measuring the average time of the processor.execute(subjectJson)

but anyway, updated

Comment: @omarmahameed, my question was about the exact setup of the polyglot engine. In particular, did you check that it's not using the slow "Interpreted" implementation which doesn't have any JIT compilation. Thanks for the details on the 6000× repetition.